# Asynchronously Load Javascript in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm putting every bit of my jQuery and JavaScript that is embedded in my HTML into my application js assets files. My goal is to load this file asynchronously. I'm using a ruby gem to install jquery so that all of my js and jquery are compiled and minified into the same file in production.

On my checkout page, I have to arrays that I was using to autoload all of the supported country/states that our website will ship products to.

The code looks like this (at the bottom of my view).

```
<script>
    var checkoutCountries = [<%= raw @countries.to_json %>];
    var checkoutStates = [<%= raw @states.to_json %>];
</script>
```

Will this cause any issues with the javascript because my main js file that will be loaded in asynchronously will reference these array variables. I would think this to not be a problem for users with faster internet connections but I am wondering if this could cause issues elsewhere? Should this be handled differently all together? Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: It was always my understanding that `async` should be used for files you do not need to rely on being there, it sounds like you need those files there to provide those variables, in which case, loading them `async` would be a bad idea.

Comment: I think what you’re asking is “can js files loaded with async execute before inline scripts”.  The answer seems to be “yes”.  [reference](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/)

Comment: @James with that being the case, should I put the javascript that uses the array inside the same script tag embedded in the html? I'm trying to get a higher page speed score from Google page speed insights which should hopefully help with SEO.

Comment: Couldn't you just make an ajax request at the beginning of your main script...? Why go through this trouble

Comment: I would save async script loads for "definitions" and non-async or in-line scripts for "actually does stuff" - so yes, putting the portion of your script that uses the array inline might work well.

Comment: @James I think that is what I will do. All of the JavaScript (except for this one function that sets the country/state) is simply click/onchange events that submit forms, expand lists, etc. Would these click events be okay to load in asynchronously or would that be considered code that "actually does stuff" in your comment above.

Comment: It depends on whether those click/onchange assignments need document elements to exist first.